# Automatic insert mode and normal mode switching

Tags: key-bindings, insert-mode, normal-mode

Coming from emacs, jumping to the end of the line is easy:

```
CTRL + E
```

I have been recently trying out Vim, and I found out you need to first exit insert mode to then use commands.

So, in Vim, I need to:

- go to normal mode: `<Esc>`
- jump to end of line: `$`
- go to insert mode: `i`

Is there any way to automate this?

Comment: Note there are more commands to go to insert mode than just `i`; for example `A` will put the cursor at the end of the line and go to insert mode, `o` opens a new line, etc. See `:help inserting` for a complete list and docs.

Answer (score 4):

If your terminal has support, you can simply press <kbd>End</kbd>.

Otherwise, use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd> to get into normal mode for a single command only. So `Ctrl-O` and then `$` (or `A`) will do the trick.

In principle, you can remap `Ctrl-E` to do `Ctrl-O $` (like `inoremap <c-e> <c-o>$`), but `:h i_ctrl-e` is sometimes useful in Vim on its own.